# Can't switch users anymore

Tags: 14.04, users

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and update regularly. I have 3 users on the system.  I can log in to one user, but no longer can switch to another user without getting black screen and apparent crash.  Only remedy I've found so far is a hard reboot. This worked prior to 14.04.  So the question is this:  how can I log into multiple user accounts... and then switch between them in Trusty?  Thanks

Comment: How do you switch?  [Ctrl][Alt][F7]-[F9]?

Comment: I have the same issue. What GR card do you hace? IMO It seems it is somehow related to nvidia drivers.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt F7-F9 does work to switch logged in users, but it isn't particularly intuitive and only seems to work if the users are already logged in.  Back in the day,  you could graphically switch the users using the top panel, and they just switched w/o the black screen.   Now I'm finding I have to be logged in to one user, lock that user (Ctrl-L), and only then try to switch to a different user using the top panel applet.  This seems to work.

Comment: smrt28:  lshw lists card as a Radeon X1300/X1550 Series